# Godin Multiac Nylon : how well is that guitar adapted to classical guitar players?

Tags: guitar, midi

I would like to know if that guitar is totally replication the string length, distance and feel of a classical guitar.

And also get any opinion you may have on it.

Comment: 2 downvotes and no explanation ? I do not accept them.

Comment: Downvotes can mean a lot of things to people. They may think the question doesn't show effort, or is offtopic, or a range of other items. You kind of have to accept them though - that's the way a community system works :-) It is better when people comment, but it's not the end of the world. I think the question is a bit subjective and quite localised, myself - as individuals who have used this Godin may have differing opinions.

Comment: @DrMayhem: True :). But I did research the topic... Simply, I do Not have the classical guitar measurements in mind, so even checking Godin's specs in detail would not have helped.

Comment: I gave you a down-vote because you could have easily done a Google search or gone to the Godin website and looked up the information yourself. Most guitar manufacturers of all types publish measurements of their guitars and you could have easily compared the measurements of the Godin guitars with those of other guitar manufacturers yourself without posting a question here.

Comment: You may disagree with me, but I believe that any question that elicits the response "Why did he not do his own Google search rather than asking this question?" will result in down-votes.

Comment: Also, I don't think this site is a good place to ask for opinions about or experiences with a particular brand of guitar. That is more of a "shopping" question, which is off-topic here. There are many forums elsewhere for classical guitarists who discuss their instruments, for example, and such a question would be appropriate on one of those forums.

Comment: @SkippyFastol, please read a blog post of mine from 2009 where I discuss measurements of the guitar and how they affect playability according to the preference of the player. http://wheatwilliams.com/wordpress/?p=119

Answer (score 1):

Godin make about eight different models of electric-acoustic nylon-string guitars for different purposes. Some have a wide, flat fingerboard and scale length and string spacing just like a standard classical guitar. Some have a narrower fingerboard with a radius to it and narrower string spacing. They have [detailed specifications on their Web site](http://www.godinguitars.com/godinmultnylonseriesp.htm), with all the essential measurements in millimeters (on the French pages) or inches (on the English pages), so you can go there and read them yourself.

Comment: Stupendous answer, as always.